# knime node Subset Matcher

Tags: knime

The “subset matcher” node in “Using Association Rules” searches my products in the association rules database but returns the sorted list. For example, for the existing list in the database (21, 12, 15), “subset matcher” returns the list (12,15,21) and subsequently the association rule is not located. Can I get the lists in “AntecedentsItems” without ordering?

Comment: Why do you think this is the case? Have you checked `knime://EXAMPLES/50_Applications/16_MarketBasketAnalysis`?

Comment: I studied that case. The node "subset matcher" has an error. The searched lists are returned ordered and the association rules are not located. Is there a node that returns the unordered lists?

Comment: "Subset Matcher" node The output table contains pairs of matching cells: the current shopping basket and the total or partial matching antecedents from the rule set, but in the output table "AntecedentsItems" the values ​​are ordered and do not match the antecedents in the rule set. For example, if you enter the basket [229, 225], the output table "AntecedentsItems" is [225], [225,229] and [229]. The association [229, 225] is not found and no recommended products are located.

Comment: Are you sure, you are using Set collection types (of the right type)?

Comment: Yes, the values are sorted in the "subset matcher" node. You can check it by inserting the list (229,225) in knime: // EXAMPLES / 50_Applications / 16_MarketBasketAnalysis